# Issues with my regex in java

Tags: java, regex

Hi guys i am trying to figure out a simple regEx from the given text below:

```
<b>Name:</b> Photomatix.Pro.v4.0.64bit-FOSI<br />
```

i basically want to output and store only **Photomatix.Pro.v4.0.64bit-FOSI** i.e. the actual value thats inside the   but when i define it like this:

```
private static final String REG_NAME = "<b>Name:</b>(.*)<br />";
```

It actually stores and outputs the whole  `<b>Name:</b> Photomatix.Pro.v4.0.64bit-FOSI<br />`

Any ideas on how i can just extract the value given from the above xml text? cheers in advance

Comment: If you have only XML to parse, you should try an XML parser instead of regexes.

Comment: I've flagged the "use an XML parser instead" comment as spam/offensive - the question is very explicitly regular expression based, i.e. how to obtain a capturing group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
  final String REG_NAME = "<b>Name:</b>(.*)<br />";

        String text = "<b>Name:</b> Photomatix.Pro.v4.0.64bit-FOSI<br />";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REG_NAME);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: `group(1)` does the trick, `group(0)` is the complete match, which is equal to the OP's "unexpected" result.

Comment: edit: how does it group strings together? i would like to understand the concept of grouping.

Comment: @jonney: check it out: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html

Answer (score 1):

```
String r = "/b>(.*)<b";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( r );
Matcher m = p.matcher( "<b>Name:</b> Photomatix.Pro.v4.0.64bit-FOSI<br />" );

if ( m.find() )
{
  System.out.println( "found: " + m.group(1) );
}
```

Comment: You know full well that your answer is incorrect. It will work for a string like "b>Name:</b Photomatix.Pro.v4.0.64bit-FOSI" which is not what joneey expected. My answer is not perfect either!

Comment: indeed, but I think we gave him enough to work with. We can't know all his possible string inputs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have a Java compiler at hand right now so I cannot verify the answer. Thus this isn't the final answer, but...)

If you really want to do it with regexes, you should take a look at matchers and groups in the Java regex classes.

Answer (score 0):

well, i don't think it is such a good idea to parse an html using regexes, you should use some html java parsers. if you want to use regular expression though, you can check some examples here: [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)

Comment: i wasnt aware their was any html java parsers.